# Change WooCommerce price per product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change per product price in WooCommerce. I am looking for some hook to do it. Actually i am looking to discount product 10%. I want to do it pragmatically.

```
function woo_my_custom_message($price_html) {
   $price = trim($price_html);
   $price = (int) $price;
   return ($price*10)/100;
}
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'woo_my_custom_poa_message' );
```

Comment: i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter you're looking for is *woocommerce_get_price*. So your code will be something like:

```
function my_custom_price($price, $product) {{      
   return $price * 0.9;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'my_custom_price', 10, 2);
```